# Connecting to localhost from devices outside the network

Tags: java, server, client

I am currently doing an project at the university where we have to develop a multiplayer roleplay game with an client-server architecture. My part is to develop a Java Server which responds to client requests. 
What do i have to do so my teammembers are able to connect to my localhost server?

Comment: If a device is 'outside' the network then you need to add it to the network before it can communicate with devices on the network.

Comment: what kind of operating system (OS) do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want clients outside your local network to be able to see your server, you'll need to use something like ngrok. It's designed for exactly this. https://ngrok.com/

If your clients will be connecting from inside your network, they will need your machine's ip address. They can type it into their browser window. If you're running your java server on a port other than 80, then they'll need to add that to the url.

```
// from inside the network
example: http://192.168.1.125:80
example: http://192.168.1.125:3000
example: http://192.168.1.125:5000

// from outside the network
example: http://yourNgrokName.ngrok.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually all the computers (i.e. macOS, linux, windows) have at least a double interface (localhost) which is not reachable outside and an external interface (wifi or ethernet) that is reachable from outside.

> On most computer systems, localhost resolves to the IP address
>   127.0.0.1, which is the most commonly used IPv4 loopback address, and to the IPv6 loopback address ::1. The name localhost is also a
>   reserved top-level domain name, set aside to avoid confusion with the
>   definition as a hostname.

If you want that your team members are able to reach your computer, you have to use the address of this second interface.

But in this case, there could be many problems related to your personal firewall, network topology and etc.

The word outside itself is very generic because, outside could mean:

- computers in my home network (small size)
- computers in my office network (small-medium size), may be spread across more buildings
- all the computers on the internet

Different network problems arises when you want that you personal computer is reachable from outside.